# How to move file in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am making a VBscript in an installer that can move a shortcut to the desktop. I have tried searching about some commands but they are too confusing.

```
x = MsgBox("Would you like to create a desktop shortcut?", 0+4, "Sound Test")
If x = VbYes Then
    Dim fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim path
    Set path = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".") 
    fso.MoveFile path\SoundTest, D:\Users\[secret]\Desktop
End If
```

What am I doing wrong?

path\SoundTest is what I want to move.

Comment: Are you moving a file or a folder? I think you need [MoveFolder Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/465s5y8s(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: It is a file (shortcut)

Comment: You are missing `"`s around the arguments to `MoveFile`

Comment: `fso.MoveFile "path\SoundTest", "D:\Users\[secret]\Desktop"`

Comment: @DavidPostill: Well, `path` is a variable, so it should probably be `path + "\SoundTest"`.

Comment: @Scott True ...

Comment: IIRC to move a file into a folder a trailing \ is needed at the destination so D:\Users\[secret]\Desktop\ or even better specify the whole path of the destFile so D:\Users\[secret]\Desktop\SoundTest.lnk so it is less confusing. In case the SoundTest is not a variable the source also needs the extension (probably .lnk) and the path variable should probably be the full path and not a relative one to avoid problems with the working directory and stuff

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method here is to simply make a new shortcut.

In this way, you can set the *Target* and *Start in* (working directory) correctly without have to rely on properties that were previous set, and that may no longer be valid.

You can get the location of the user's Desktop via the "Special Folders" property, as shown below:

```
set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strDesktop = oShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

set oFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strCurrentDirectory = oFileSystem.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName)

set oLink              = oShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\Link to MyProgram.lnk")
oLink.TargetPath       = strCurrentDirectory & "\MyProgram.exe"
oLink.WorkingDirectory = strCurrentDirectory
oLink.WindowStyle      = 1
oLink.Description      = ""
oLink.IconLocation     = strCurrentDirectory & "\MyProgram.exe"
oLink.Save
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Shortcut on your Desktop and here is a complete example that i made before in vbscript :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,MyScriptPath,DJBuzzRadio,MyLoop,strComputer,objPing,objStatus,FSO,FolderScript,Icon
Title = "Radio DJ Buzz Live by © Hackoo 2018 "
MyScriptPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
Set FSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Path of the folder where the Vbscript is located
FolderScript = FSO.GetParentFolderName(MyScriptPath)
DJBuzzRadio = ChrW(104)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(112)&ChrW(58)&ChrW(47)&_
ChrW(47)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(99)&ChrW(104)&ChrW(111)&_
ChrW(99)&ChrW(114)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(105)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(115)&ChrW(46)&_
ChrW(99)&ChrW(104)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(106)&ChrW(98)&ChrW(117)&ChrW(122)&ChrW(122)&_
ChrW(114)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(105)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(95)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(105)&ChrW(110)&_
ChrW(100)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(115)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(109)&ChrW(112)&ChrW(51)&ChrW(46)&_
ChrW(97)&ChrW(115)&ChrW(120)
'To create a shortcut of this vbscript on your desktop
Call Shortcut(MyScriptPath,"DJ Buzz Radio")
MyLoop = True
If CheckConnection = True Then Call AskQuestion()
'***************************************************************************
Function CheckConnection()
    CheckConnection = False
    While MyLoop = True
        strComputer = "smtp.gmail.com"
        Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\").ExecQuery _
        ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strComputer & "'")
        For Each objStatus in objPing
            If objStatus.Statuscode = 0 Then
                MyLoop = False
                CheckConnection = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        Pause(10) 'To sleep for 10 secondes
    Wend
End Function
'***************************************************************************
Sub Play(URL)
    Dim Sound
    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")               
    Sound.URL = URL
    Sound.settings.volume = 100                               
    Sound.Controls.play                                     
    do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0                
        wscript.sleep 100                                       
    loop                                                    
    wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000 
End Sub
'***************************************************************************
Sub Shortcut(Application_Path,ShortcutName)
    Dim objShell,fso,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab,strCurDir
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strCurDir = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
    MyTab = Split(Application_Path,"\")
    If ShortcutName = "" Then
        ShortcutName = MyTab(UBound(MyTab))
    End if
    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\" & ShortcutName & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(Application_Path)
    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,138"
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
'*****************************************************************************
'Function to add double quotes in a variable
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*****************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function    
'******************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'******************************************************************************
Sub Pause(NSeconds)
    Wscript.Sleep(NSeconds*1000)
End Sub
'******************************************************************************
Sub AskQuestion()
    Dim Question,MsgAR,MsgFR,MsgEN
    MsgFR = "Voulez-vous écouter DJ Buzz Radio en direct ?" & vbcr &_
    "Oui = Pour écouter la radio" & vbcr & "Non = Pour arrêter la radio" & vbcr & String(50,"*")
    MsgEN = "Did you want to listen to the Radio DJ Buzz Live ?" & vbcr &_
    "Yes = To Listen to the Radio" & vbcr &_
    "No = To Stop the Radio" & vbcr & String(50,"*")
    MsgAR = ChrW(1607)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1585)&ChrW(1610)&ChrW(1583)&_ 
    ChrW(32)&ChrW(1571)&ChrW(1606)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1587)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(1593)&ChrW(32)&_ 
    ChrW(32)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1610)&ChrW(1601)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1585)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1583)&_
    ChrW(1610)&ChrW(1608)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(68)&ChrW(74)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(66)&ChrW(117)&ChrW(122)&ChrW(122)&_ 
    ChrW(32)&ChrW(82)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(105)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(63) & vbcr & ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1593)&_ 
    ChrW(1605)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(61)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1587)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1593) & vbcr &_
    ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(61)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1608)&ChrW(1602)&ChrW(1601) & vbcr & String(50,"*")
    Question = MsgBox(MsgFR & vbcr & MsgEN & vbcr & MsgAR,vbYesNO+vbQuestion+vbSystemModal,Title)
    If Question = VbYes And Not AppPrevInstance() Then
        Call Play(DJBuzzRadio)
    End If
    If Question = VbYes And AppPrevInstance() Then 
        MsgBox "There is another instance in execution !" & VbCrLF &_
        "Il y a une autre instance en cours d'exécution !"& VbcrLF &_
        ChrW(1607)&ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1603)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1605)&_ 
        ChrW(1579)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1570)&ChrW(1582)&_ 
        ChrW(1585)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1601)&ChrW(1610)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1575)&_ 
        ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1601)&ChrW(1610)&ChrW(1584)& VbcrLF &_
        CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation+vbSystemModal,Title    
        WScript.Quit()
    End If
    If Question = VbNo And Not AppPrevInstance() Then
        Call Kill("wscript.exe")
    End If
    If Question = VbNo And AppPrevInstance() Then
        Call Kill("wscript.exe")
    End If
End Sub
'******************************************************************************
Sub Kill(MyProcess)
    Dim Titre,colItems,objItem,Processus,Question
    Titre = " Processus "& DblQuote(MyProcess) &" en cours d'exécution "
    Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process " _
    & "Where Name like '%"& MyProcess &"%' AND commandline like " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "",,48)
    For Each objItem in colItems
        objItem.Terminate(0)'Kill this process
    Next
End Sub
'******************************************************************************
```